# Google Sheet copy data from one sheet to another and return last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I want to copy data from one sheet to another in google sheets. The cells in the rows are in a different order than they need to be on the final sheet. I have an index function imbedded in the macro. I have several sheets that need to be added into the consolidated sheet but I am running it 1 at a time right now. My issue is that when I run the macro, I need it to pick up the content of the last filled in row on Sheet 1 (Sege) and drop it into the next empty row on the main sheet (Consoldidated). No attachmen to row numberHere is my code:

function myFunction() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SEGE'), true);
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1, 2).activate();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated '), true);
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[2])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=INDEX(SEGE!R[0]C[2])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Sege');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 3).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[4])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=INDEX(SEGE!R[0]C[2])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
```

};

edit: here is my second attempt with the answer but it ignored the first function and just copied the last row exactly so wrong data in the wrong column

```
function SegeNewRowmaybe() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('SEGE'),);
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1, 2).activate();
var ts = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Consolidated '),);
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[2])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=INDEX(SEGE!R[0]C[2])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setValue('Sege');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 3).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();

ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[4])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=INDEX(SEGE!R[0]C[2])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(SEGE!R[0]C[3])');
ts.appendRow(getLastRowValues_('SEGE'))
};

function getLastRowValues_() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const segesheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sege')
 
 const keyValuesB = (
    segesheet.getRange(1,3, segesheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = keyValuesB.length - 1;
  while (row && !keyValuesB[row].join('Consolidated')) row--;
  return segesheet.getDataRange().getValues()[row];
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getLastRowValues_()` utility function to get the values in the last row of a sheet, and `Sheet.appendRows()` to append them to the 'Consolidated ' sheet, like this:

```
/**
* An example of how to use the getLastRowValues_() utility function.
* Gets the values in the last row of several sheets and appends some
* of those values, together with the name of each sheet, to the bottom
* of a target sheet.
*/
function appendLastRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Consolidated ');
  const sourceSheetRegex = /^(SEGE|Sheet2|Sheet3|Sheet4)$/i;
  ss.getSheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    if (sheetName.match(sourceSheetRegex)) {
      const values = getLastRowValues_(sheet);
      const rowToAppend = [sheetName, values[0], values[1], values[3], values[4], values[2]];
      targetSheet.appendRow(rowToAppend);
    }
  });
}


/**
* Gets the values in the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the values in the last row that has visible
* content in any column.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} columnNumber Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet.
* @return {Object[]} The values in the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRowValues_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 19 August 2022
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73415105/13045193
  const keyValues = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = keyValues.length - 1;
  while (row && !keyValues[row].join('')) row--;
  return sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[row];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried to pair your second solution to my current code and it ran the last row but copied it exactly so the wrong data was in the wrong columns. Could you clarify this more? sorry i am pretty new at this

Comment: Edited the answer to add an example of how to append only some of the last row values. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).